# What does ''$p$ of order $10\mod 11$'' mean?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> What does ''$p$ of order $10\mod 11$'' mean ?

$p$ is a prime, what are then the possibilities for $p$ ?

Comment: Do you desire to know the definition of order, or do you already know that, but wish to characterize the elements that have order $10$ modulo $11?$

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't know the definition but Ethan has already answered it, by fooling around I found that $2,6,7,8$ are the elements, thanks

Comment: @user257 I don't think the answer in your comment is right. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the powers of $p$ mod 11 the first power you find whose value is 1 (mod 11) is the order of $p$ mod 11.

I assume that your second question means "what can the order of $p$ be for the various primes $p$? If you try out several you should be able to guess the answer.

For example, for $p=3$ we have $3^2 = 9$, $3^3 = 27 \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$,
$3^4 \equiv 3 \times 5 = 15 \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$ and $3^5 \equiv 3 \times 4 = 12 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ so the order of the prime $3$ is $5$. That means $5$ is one of the possible orders asked for.

If you work this out for $p=2$ you will find that its order is $10$.

Comment: Note that there are infinitely many primes in each nonzero congruence class $\mod 11$, by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael True - but it's a stretch for the OP at this stage of his or her studies to be able to say that the "prime" hypothesis is irrelevant.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Yes $3^5\equiv 1\mod 10$ but then the order is $5$, so it is out of question I need only the elements (primes)$\le11$ of order $10$, and these are $2,6,7,8$

Comment: @user257 You have correctly found the four elements of order 10 (mod 11). That may be the question you wanted to ask, but it's not the one you did ask - that one was about primes. (Typo In your comment: you mean mod 11, not mod 10.)